# How can I change the style of warning on resharper? (want to get rid of curly underline)

Tags: resharper, resharper-7.0, resharper-7.1

Whenever I open legacy or third party code that does not comply with my stylecop settings I get loads of blue underlines (warnings). This makes it quite hard to read the code as it adds a loads of line noise.

Is there a way of changing this curly underline style for warnings (or disable it) in resharper without having to switch of the whole code analysis?

I'm running resharper 7.1.1

Answer (score 3):

I only have Resharper 5.1 at work, but it should be similar in 7.1.1

Navigate to:

ReSharper->Options...->Code Inspection->Inspection Severity

and change:

StyleCop - Defaults (Requires VS Restart)->Default Violation Severity

to 'Show as hint'

And then restart VS.

[image]

Alternatively you can use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ALT` + `8` (default VS keymap) to temporarily turn code analysis off / on.

Additionally, you can have individual 'Settings.StyleCop' settings files per project so you could create one for your legacy project to ignore everything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I think they've taken away that option in Resharper 7.X

Comment: Thought that may have been a StyleCop setting rather than ReSharper, are you running the latest StyleCop plugin (4.7.42)?

Comment: Just checked on 7.1.1, and you are right, the above option is no longer available, that's a shame. Doing them manually will take a bit of time.

Comment: I am running that version of StyleCop. I can control what rules get added and removed via StyleCop settings, but not the way they're displayed. I think that is what resharper is doing.